# itemmouseleave event is not getting called if we move cursor quickly

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, extjs4.1, mouseleave, gridpanel

I have treepanel. On some specific condition I want to show image on mouse enter and remove that image on mouseleave in treenode. but when i hover the mouse quickly image get added but not getting removed as itemmouseleave event is not getting fired. 
I have prepared jsfiidle to understand my problem in which I am trying to change text of node on mouseenter and mouseleave. on slow motion it is working fine but if hover quickly it shows mouseenter even if we are away from node.

Link to jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/79ZkX/238/

```
Ext.create("Ext.tree.Panel", {
  title: "Car Simple Tree",
  width: 400,
  height: 600,
  store: store,
  rootVisible: false,
  lines: true, // will show lines to display hierarchy.
  useArrows: true, //this is a cool feature - converts the + signs into Windows-7 like arrows. "lines" will not be displayed
  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
  listeners: {
    itemmouseenter: function(_this, _item) {
      var name = _item.get("name");
      _item.set("name", "mouseenter");
    },

    itemmouseleave: function(_this, _item) {
      //var name = _item.get('name');
      _item.set("name", "leave");
    }
  },
  columns: [
    {
      xtype: "treecolumn",
      dataIndex: "name", // value field which will be displayed on screen
      flex: 1
    }
  ]
});
```

I want to remove the image on mouseleave. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added manual workaround for this. On Fast Mouse Hover itemmouseleave event will not get triggered. so i am maintaining array of hovered node and on mouseenter of node, checking if array contain element then set text of that node.

added code to this jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/79ZkX/250/

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
title: 'Car Simple Tree',
width: 400,
height: 600,
store: store,
rootVisible: false,
visibleNodes: [],
lines: true, // will show lines to display hierarchy.    
useArrows: true, //this is a cool feature - converts the + signs into Windows-7 like arrows. "lines" will not be displayed
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
listeners : {

    itemmouseenter: function(_this, _item) {
for (var i = 0; i < this.visibleNodes.length; i++) {
        var node = this.visibleNodes[i];
        node.set('name', "leave");
        this.visibleNodes.splice(i, 1);
    }
        var name = _item.get('name');
        _item.set('name', "mouseenter");
        this.visibleNodes.push(_item);

    },

    itemmouseleave: function(_this, _item) {
            //var name = _item.get('name');
        _item.set('name', "leave");
  var index = this.visibleNodes.indexOf(_node);

    if (index != -1){
        this.visibleNodes.splice(index, 1);
    }
    },

},
columns: [{
    xtype: 'treecolumn',
    dataIndex: 'name', // value field which will be displayed on screen   
    flex: 1
}]
```

});